# How to filter date ranges with filter string (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, where-clause

I am trying to filter date ranges based on an input string in SQL Server.

```
-- 'All Years', '30', '60', '90', '2019', '2020', etc.
declare @dateRange nvarchar(20) = '90' 

select 
[date],
[data]
from someTable
where (
  @dateRange = case @dateRange
  when 30 then date >= getDate() - 30
  when 60 then date >= getDate() - 60
  when 90 then date >= getDate() - 90
  when 'All Years' then date
  else datePart('year', date) = @dateRange
  end
)
```

How can I case the where clause to select date ranges?

Comment: what "date range" is `'2019'`? YOu're overly complicating the problem. Have 2 parameters, a start date and an end date and use `>=` and `<` logic.

Comment: `< 100` is day range, `> 2000` is year range

Comment: 2000 isn't a range, it's a number. As is 100. Ranges would be something like 30-60, or for dates, 2020-01-01 to 2020-06-30.

Comment: They're implied ranges... Last 30 days, All of 2019, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using boolean logic rather than a `case` expression. This gives you more fine-grained control - although the logic is still cumbersome, and could probably be simplified by adopting another approach.

```
where 
    (
        @dateRage in ('30', '60', '90') 
        and date >= getDate - try_cast(@dateRange as int)
    )
    or @dateRange = 'All Years'
    or (
        @dateRage not in ('30', '60', '90', 'All Years')
        and datePart('year', date) = @dateRange
    )
)
```

Since a year would never match `'30'`, `'60'`, `'90'` or `'All Years'`, the last expression can probably be simplified:

```
where 
    (
        @dateRage in ('30', '60', '90') 
        and date >= getDate - try_cast(@dateRange as int)
    )
    or @dateRange = 'All Years'
    or datePart('year', date) = @dateRange
)
```

---

**Edit** - from the comments:

> < 100 is day range, > 2000 is year range

This makes things a little simpler:

```
where 
    @dateRange = 'All Years'
    or (
        try_cast(@dateRage as int) < 100 
        and date >= getDate - try_cast(@dateRange as int)
    )
    or (
        try_cast(@dateRage as int) > 2000 
        and datePart('year', date) = @dateRange
    )
```

Comment: Getting `Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'All Years' to data type int.` when `@dateRange nvarchar(20) = 'All Years'`.

Comment: `and datePart('year', date) = @dateRange` isn't going to do well for SARGability, mind.

Comment: @Matthew: ah yes, of course. We need `try_cast()` instead. Fixed

Answer (score 0):

You're overly complicating the issue. Don't use a single parameter to do the work of what should be 2. Use a start and end date, and then pass `NULL` for both if you want "everything":

```sql
DECLARE @Startdate date,
        @EndDate date;

--SET @StartDate = ...
--SET @EndDate = ...        

SELECT [date],
       [data]
FROM someTable
WHERE ([date] >= @StartDate AND [date] < @EndDate)
   OR (@StartDate IS NULL AND @EndDate IS NULL)
OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```

The recompile is there as the catch-all part of the query can cause bad query plan caching, so it's better to regenerate it each time.

*If* for some unknown reason, you have to pass the string (I really suggest you don't, and fix the design), then use some `CASE` expressions to set the start and end dates:

```sql
DECLARE @Param varchar(15);

DECLARE @Startdate date,
        @EndDate date;

SELECT @StartDate = CASE WHEN TRY_CONVERT(int,@Param) < 1000 THEN DATEADD(DAY, TRY_CONVERT(int,@Param) * -1, GETDATE())
                         WHEN TRY_CONVERT(int,@Param) > 1000 THEN DATEFROMPARTS(TRY_CONVERT(int,@Param),1,1)
                    END,
       @EndDate = CASE WHEN TRY_CONVERT(int,@Param) < 1000 THEN DATEADD(DAY,1,GETDATE())
                       WHEN TRY_CONVERT(int,@Param) > 1000 THEN DATEFROMPARTS(TRY_CONVERT(int,@Param)+1,1,1)
                  END;
```

As you can see, the logic is really odd, and the `TRY_CONVERT`s really muddy things, so this is not the suggested method.